# c++ structure: repeat set of functions at a certain time rate

Tags: c++, time, structure

*So I'm stuck with a little c++ program. I use "codeblocks" in a w7 environment.*

I made a function which shows a ASCII map and a marker. A second function updates the markers position on that map.

I would like to know how I could make my main structure so that the marker gets updated and the map showed, and this repeated at a certain time rate. Which functions can I use to make this happen. What strategy should I follow?

```
every x times/second DO { showmap(); updatePosition();}
```

I am a c++ beginner and I hope you can help!

Comment: Have you looked at using a Timer?

Comment: People using "sleep" below are hinting at using a thread, which is admittedly an advanced concept for a beginner (but the correct one)... just be aware that if you want your program to do multiple things at once independently (like say, one function updates a map and a second one is waiting for user input) you'd need two threads to make sure one function isn't held up while the other sleeps.

Comment: so that would be 2 DO while loops witch both call a usleep() thread?

Comment: It is more complicated than that. If you used two loops on the same thread, neither thing would be done while the thread slept, and neither could be done "simultaneously" (I put that in quotes because unless you have multiple CPU cores running thread seperately, it isn't truly simultaneous). Since you say you are in a Windows environment, understanding the event loop Ambroz mentioned is important for picking up Windows events. Also, if you are using .NET, you can use the Thread class support there. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx#Y5676

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop with usleep

```
unsigned XtimesPerSecond = 5;    // for example
unsigned long long microseconds = 1000000 / XtimesPerSecond;

do
{
    showmap();
    updatePosition();
    usleep(microseconds);
} while(true);
```

Comment: thanx for the answers everyone. This solution did the trick rather quick. For the ones who want to use this: the header for usleep is unistd.h!

Comment: Strange, you say you are on windows, but isn't that a POSIX header? Are you using Cygwin or MinGW?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what else your program needs to be doing, you may need to employ **[event driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)**. If updating that marker is the only thing it will be doing, a simple while loop with a sleep will suffice, as demonstrated in other answers.

In order to do event driven programming you generally need an **event loop** - which is a function that you call in main, which waits for events and dispatches them. Most event loops will provide *timer events* - where, basically, you ask the event loop to call function X after a given time interval elapses.

You most likely don't want to write your own event loop. There are many choices for an event loop, depending on many things like programming language and required portability.

Some examples of event loops:

- the [Qt event loop](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html),
- the [GLib event loop](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html),
- the [Windows event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows), and many more...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you want to implement an infinite loop like games engine does.

Try to do this:

```
while (true)
{
    showmap();
    updatePosition();
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Alternately, you could have a variable keep track of the last time it was run.  If the time difference between "now" and the last run is great enough, run the functions then update the variable.