# Doing something x milliseconds, processor independently

Tags: c++

I am writing a server in C++ and I want it to do something every x milliseconds. This is something I've never needed before so I googled a bit and noticed two options.

sleep(x) and clock_t()

Which of those two would be preferred? I tried it with clock_t and if I noticed that 1000 clock ticks seems to be a second. Is this always like this or was I just lucky?

I'd like some more information on this if possible.

Comment: If you want it to work portably, use the standard library. We have `chrono` and we have `thread`.

Comment: That totally depends on your use case, but `sleep(x)` blocks your current thread, which is something you would want to avoid in a servers main processing loop.

Comment: How precise do you need it to be?  Is it OK if the interval is 10 milliseconds the first time, 14 the second, 33 the third, then back to 10, or does it need to be very consistent?

Comment: Most operating systems are not realtime and they don't always fire events exactly when you want them to.  This is particularly true in VMs that most servers use these days.

Comment: I guess there are a lot of dupes, I've found this one, but the answers are quite bad imho: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956239/c-structure-repeat-set-of-functions-at-a-certain-timerate

Comment: I need it to be as exact as possible. It's going to be used to send data to the clients